# Why is Slack channel not found when posting a file using the WebAPI?

Tags: node.js, typescript, slack-api

I'm trying to post a file to a Slack channel using the Slack Web API:

```
import { WebClient } from '@slack/web-api';

export async function sendCSVToSlack(
  token: string,
  channel: string,
  csv_string: string,
  file_name: string,
  comment: string,
): Promise<void> {
  const web = new WebClient(token);
  await web.files.uploadV2({
    channel_id: channel,
    file: Buffer.from(csv_string, "utf-8"),
    filename: file_name,
    initial_comment: comment,
  });
}
```

The channel name is correct, the Slack app has the files:write scope, it has been installed and added to the channel in question but still the above invocation results in `error: 'channel_not_found'`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I used the channel name and not the channel id in the request which is why it couldn't find the channel.

Posting the answer here if anyone else runs in to the same issue.